# xp:pager control not working

Tags: java, xpages

In my xpages application I have set a pager control for a repeat control as followed:

```
<xp:pager layout="Previous Group Next"
        partialRefresh="true" id="pager1" for="rptEmployees">
</xp:pager>
```

The repeat control data is bound to a managed bean as followed:

```
<xp:repeat id="rptEmployees" rows="10" value="#{employeeBean.employees}" var="person" indexVar="index">...
```

employeeBean.employees is a list of Employee objects:

```
private List<Employee> employees;
```

The pager spots when there are more items in the repeat to be displayed, but navigating to the next set simply does not work. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What interface does your bean implement?

Comment: none: public class EmployeeBean implements Serializable{

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible causes I've come across.

1. A pager in a custom control different to where the View Panel / Data View it manages doesn't work.
2. If the XPage / app is stateless (`viewState="nostate"`), the pager will just act relative to the default state, i.e. Next Page only goes to next page from default, i.e. page 2

Comment: I have not come so far to order my xpage into several components e.g. custom controls so everything is on one xpage. The viewstate I have never set. I am not even sure where I can set this?